# Undefined offset: 1 in /vendor/magento/framework/App/Language/Dictionary.php

Tags: language, package, translate

i'm trying to extend a package language that already exists. My custom text override the texts of the package. When i try to access my site after run the follow commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy pt_BR --theme Magento/backend
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy pt_BR --theme MyCompany/MyTheme
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
chmod 777 -R var/ pub/
```

The error is:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:104:"Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /srv/www/vendor/magento/framework/App/Language/Dictionary.php on line 196";i:1;s:4066:"#0 /srv/www/vendor/magento/framework/App/Language/Dictionary.php(196): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8, 'Undefined offse...', '/srv/www/vendor...', 196, Array)
#1 /srv/www/vendor/magento/framework/App/Language/Dictionary.php(113): Magento\Framework\App\Language\Dictionary->readPackCsv('bleez', 'pt_br')
#2 /srv/www/vendor/magento/framework/Translate.php(325): Magento\Framework\App\Language\Dictionary->getDictionary('pt_BR')
#3 /srv/www/vendor/magento/framework/Translate.php(181): Magento\Framework\Translate->_loadPackTranslation()
#4 /srv/www/vendor/magento/framework/App/Area.php(240): Magento\Framework\Translate->loadData(NULL, false)
#5 /srv/www/vendor/magento/framework/App/Area.php(211): Magento\Framework\App\Area->_initTranslate()
#6 /srv/www/vendor/magento/framework/App/Area.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\Area->_loadPart('translate')
#7 /srv/www/vendor/magento/framework/View/DesignLoader.php(55): Magento\Framework\App\Area->load('translate')
#8 /srv/www/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Plugin/Design.php(48): Magento\Framework\View\DesignLoader->load()
#9 /srv/www/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(52): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Plugin\Design->beforeDispatch(Object(Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#10 /srv/www/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Backend...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'adminMassaction...')
#11 /srv/www/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/MassactionKey.php(33): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#12 /srv/www/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#13 /srv/www/var/generation/Magento/Backend/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#14 /srv/www/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#15 /srv/www/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#16 /srv/www/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#17 /srv/www/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#18 /srv/www/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 /srv/www/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#20 /srv/www/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#21 /srv/www/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 /srv/www/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#23 /srv/www/pub/index.php(37): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#24 {main}";s:3:"url";s:8:"/adminsc";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

My csv file (translated):

```
"Add New Addresses","Adicionar Novo Endereço"
"New Addresses","Novos Endereços"
"New","Novo"
"Addresses","Endereços"
"Enable Product","Ativar Produto"
"Customer Information","Informação do Cliente"
"Customer information","Informação do Cliente"
"Customers Now Online","Clientes Online Agora"
"Associate to Website","Associado ao Website"
"view","Visualizar"
"View","Visualizar"
"Print","Imprimir"
"print","Imprimir"
"the order confirmation email was sent","Email de confirmação de pedido foi enviado"
"The order confirmation email was sent","Email de confirmação de pedido foi enviado"
"the order confirmation email is not sent","Email de confirmação de pedido não foi enviado"
"The order confirmation email is not sent","Email de confirmação de pedido não foi enviado"
"Order # %1","Pedido # %1"
"Order # ","Pedido # "
"Payment & Shipping Method","Pagamento e Frete"
"Payment &amp; Shipping Method","Pagamento e Frete"
"Items Invoiced","Itens Faturados"
"credit memo","Nota de Crédito"
"Credit Memo","Nota de Crédito"
"Shipment","Envio"
"shipment","Envio"
"order","Pedido"
"Order","Pedido"
"Information","Informação"
"Shipping & Handling Information","Informações de Envio e Manuseio"
"Shipping &amp; Handling Information","Informações de Envio e Manuseio"
"Shipping and Tracking Information","Informação de envio e rastreamento"
"Track Order","Acompanhar Pedido"
"Ship Date","Data do Envio"
"Total Quantity","Quantidade Total"
"Carrier","Transportadora"
"Apply Filters","Aplicar Filtros"
"Items Refunded","Itens Reembolsados"
"Refund","Reembolso"
"Memo Total","Valor Total"
"Credit Memo History","Histórico de Notas de Crédito"
"Credit Memo Totals","Valor Total do Crédito"
"Not Notified","Não Notificado"
"Notified","Notificado"
"from","a partir de"
"to","para"
"${ $.visible } out of ${ $.total } visible","${ $.visible } de ${ $.total } visíveis"
"Description","Descrição"
"description","Descrição"
"Display Mode","Modo de Exibição"
"Available Product Listing Sort By","Lista de Produtos Disponíveis e classificar por"
"Enable Product","Ativar Produto"
"Product Name","Nome do Produto"
"Price","Preço"
"price","Preço"
"Tax Class","Classe de Taxa"
"Weight","Peso"
"Categories","Categorias"
"Visibility","Visibilidade"
"Country of Manufacture","País de Fabricação"
"content","Conteúdo"
"Content","Conteúdo"
"Short Description","Descrição Curta"
"Display Product Options In","Exibir opções do produto em"
"Attributes","Atributos"
"Special Price","Preço Especial"
"Cost","Custo"
"Advanced Inventory","Inventário Avançado"
"done","Pronto"
"Done","Pronto"
"Save & Duplicate","Salvar e Duplicar"
"Save & Close","Salvar e Fechar"
"cancel","Cancelar"
"Cancel","Cancelar"
"Add Selected","Adicionar Selecionado"
"Select Attribute","Selecione o Atributo"
"records found","registros encontrados"
"No records found","Sem registros encontrados"
"Selected Attributes:","Atributos Selecionados:"
"group","Grupo"
"Group","Grupo"
"phone","Telefone"
"Phone","Telefone"
"Account Created in","Conta Criada em"
"Account Created In","Conta Criada em"
"Edit Review","Editar Revisão"
"Too many password reset requests. Please wait and try again or contact hello@example.com.","Muitos pedidos se recuperação de senha feitos. Tente novamente mais tarde."
"Are you sure you want to send an order email to customer?","Tem certeza de que deseja enviar um e-mail de pedido para o cliente?"
"You sent the order email.","Você enviou o e-mail do pedido."
"The invoice has been created.","A fatura foi criada."
"We can't send the invoice email.","Não podemos enviar o e-mail da fatura."
"We can't send the shipment.","We can't send the shipment."
"We can't save the invoice.","Não podemos enviar a fatura."
"The invoice has been captured.","A fatura foi capturada."
"You created the credit memo.","Você criou o memorando de crédito."
"A customer with the same email already exists in an associated website.","Um cliente com o mesmo e-mail já existe em um site associado."
"Are you sure you want to cancel this order?","Tem certeza de que deseja cancelar este pedido?"
"Provided Zip/Postal Code seems to be invalid. Example: 12345-6789; 12345. If you believe it is the right one you can ignore this notice.","Aparentemente seu CEP é inválido ou não há registro de endereço dele."
"Provided Zip/Postal Code seems to be invalid. Example: 12345; 12345-678. If you believe it is the right one you can ignore this notice.","Aparentemente seu CEP é inválido ou não há registro de endereço dele."
"An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again.","Ocorreu um erro no servidor. Por favor, tente fazer o pedido novamente."
"You sent the shipment.","Você enviou a remessa."
"You saved the customer.","Você salvou o cliente."
"Current User Identity Verification","Verificação atual da identidade do usuário"
"Interface Locale","Interface Locale"
"Report Bugs","Reportar Erros"
"Author","Autor"
"author","Autor"
"Summary Rating","Classificação resumida"
"Detailed Rating","Classificação detalhada"
"Save and Previous","Salvar e retornar"
"Account Lock","Bloqueio de conta"
"Confirmed email","E-mail confirmado"
"Force Sign-In","Forçar login"
"Group","Grupo"
"Add New","Adicionar Novo"
"Purchased","Comprado"
"Add New Endereços","Adicionar Novo Endereço"
"Purchased From: %1","Comprado a partir de:% 1"
"Newsletter Information","Informação da Newsletter"
"Subscribed to Newsletter","Assinado na Newsletter"
"Start Date","Data de Início"
"End Date","Data final"
"Receive Date","Data de recebimento"
"Subject","Assunto"
"No Newsletter Found","Não foi encontrado nenhuma Newsletter"
"Add Locale","Adicionar Local"
"Add Date","Adicionar Data"
"Customer First Name","Nome do Cliente"
"Customer Last Name","Sobrenome do Cliente"
"Currently Active","Atualmente Ativo"
"Usage limit enforced for logged in customers only.","Limite de uso imposta apenas para clientes registrados."
"Priority","Prioridade"
"Public In RSS Feed","Publicar no Feed RSS"
"Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To","o desconto de quantidade máxima é aplicado para"
"Discount Qty Step (Buy X)","Desconto por Quantidade (Comprar X)"
"Discard subsequent rules","Descarte as regras subseqüentes"
"Free Shipping","Frete Grátis"
"Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions ' '(leave blank for all items).","Aplicar a regra aos itens do carrinho que correspondem as seguintes condições ' '(Deixe em branco para todos os items)."
"Apply the rule only if the following conditions are met (leave blank for all products).","Aplicar a regra somente se as seguintes condições forem verdade (Deixe em branco para todos os produtos)."
"Default Rule Label for All Store Views","Campo de regra padrão para todas as visualizações da loja"
"Store View Specific Labels","Exibir campos específicos da loja"
Attention,Atenção
"Something went wrong.","Algo deu errado."
"Maximum 255 chars. Meta Description should optimally be between 150-160 characters","Máximo de 255 caracteres. Recomendado entre 150 e 160 caracteres"
"Display Product Options In","Exibição das Opções do Produto"
"Layout Update XML","Atualização de layout XML"
"Schedule Design Update","Agendamento de Mudança de Layout"
"New Theme","Novo Tema"
"New Layout","Novo Layout"
"Gift Options","Opções de Presente"
"Allow Gift Message","Permitir Mensagem de Presente"
"Unsubscribe from Newsletter","Remover de Newsletter"
"Unsubscribe","Cancelar inscrição"
"Select Visible","Marque o Visível"
"Unselect Visible","Desmarque o Visível"
"No Coupon","Sem cupom"
"For matching items only","Apenas para produtos correspondentes"
"For shipment with matching items","Para envio com itens correspondentes"
"Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items).","Aplique a regra somente aos itens do carrinho correspondendo às seguintes condições (deixe em branco para todos os itens)."
"Row total in cart","Total da fila no carrinho"
"New Catalog Price Rule","Nova Regra de Preço do Catálogo"
"Price Rule","Regra de Preço"
"What is this?","O que é isso?"
"Free Amount","Quantidade Gratuita"
"New Accounts Report","Relatório de novas contas"
"New Accounts","Novas Contas"
"New Account","Nova Conta"
"Rule Name","Nome da Regra"
"Conditions (don\'t add conditions if rule is applied to all products)","Condições (não inclua condições se a regra for aplicada a todos os produtos)"
"Save and Apply","Salvar e Aplicar"
"Apply","Aplicar"
"Event","Evento"
"Apply as percentage of original","Aplicar como porcentagem do original"
"Adjust final price to this percentage","Ajustar o preço final para esta porcentagem"
"Adjust final price to discount value","Ajustar o preço final ao valor de desconto"
"Discount Amount","Valor de Desconto"
"Apply as fixed amount","Aplicar como valor fixo"
"Most viewed","Mais Visualizados"
"Configuration","Configuração"
"Translations","Traduções"
"Translation files","Arquivos de tradução"
"Additional Cache Management","Gerenciamento de cache adicional"
"environment","Ambiente"
"Environment","Ambiente"
"Transaction Code","Código de Transação"
"Last Activity","Última atividade"
"Products in Cart","Produtos no Carrinho"
"Products in Carts","Produtos em Carrinho"
"Abandoned Carts","Carrinhos Abandonados"
"Abandoned Cart","Carrinho Abandonado"
"Newsletter Problems Report","Relatório de Problemas da Newsletter"
"Newsletter Problem Reports","Relatórios de Problemas da Newsletter"
"Product Reviews Report","Relatório de comentários de produtos"
"Customer Reviews Report","Relatório de Comentários de Clientes"
"Customers Report","Relatório de Clientes"
"By Customers","Por clientes"
"By Products","Por produtos"
"Coupons","Cupons"
"PayPal Settlement","Liquidação Paypal"
"Braintree Settlement","Liquidação Braintree"
"Order Count","Contagem de pedidos"
"Low stock","Estoque Baixo"
"Refresh Statistics","Atualizar estatísticas"
"We found no problems.","Não encontramos problemas."
"subscriber","Assinante"
"Subscriber","Assinante"
"Queue Start Date","Data de Início da Fila"
"Queue Subject","Assunto da Fila"
"Error Code","Código do Erro"
"Error Text","Texto do Erro"
"Orders Report","Relatório de Pedidos"
"For accurate reporting, be sure to refresh lifetime statistics whenever you change the time zone.","Para relatórios precisos, assegure-se de atualizar as estatísticas de vida útil sempre que você alterar o fuso horário."
"Last updated: %1. To refresh last day\'s <a href=""%2"">statistics</a>, click <a href=""%3"">here</a>.","Última atualização: %1.  Para atualizar o último dia as <a href=""%2"">estatísticas</a>, clique <a href=""%3"">aqui</a>."
"undefined","Indefinido"
"Undefined","Indefinido"
"Date Used","Data de utilização"
"Order Created","Pedido Criado"
"Order Updated","Pedido Atualizado"
"The Order Updated report is created in real time and does not require a refresh.","O relatório Atualizado por ordem é criado em tempo real e não requer uma atualização."
"Period","Período"
"period","Período"
"Day","Dia"
"day","Dia"
"rate","Taxa"
"Rate","Taxa"
"Show Report","Exibir Relatórios"
"Interval","Intervalo"
"Invoice Report","Relatório de Fatura"
"Empty Rows","Linhas Vazias"
"Show Actual Values","Mostrar Valores Reais"
"Applies to Any of the Specified Order Statuses except canceled orders","Aplica-se a qualquer um dos estados de pedido especificados, exceto ordens canceladas"
"specified","Específico"
"Specified","Específico"
"Sales Items","Itens de vendas"
"Sales Total","Total de vendas"
"Sales Tax","Imposto sobre as vendas"
"Sales Shipping","Envio de vendas"
"Sales Discount","Desconto de vendas"
"Tax Report","Relatório Fiscal"
"Invoiced Orders","Encomendas faturadas"
"Total Invoiced","Total Faturado"
"Paid Invoices","Faturas Pagas"
"Unpaid Invoices","Faturas Não Pagas"
"Shipping Report","Relatório de Envio"
"Carrier/Method","Transportadora / Método"
"Total Sales Shipping","total de Vendas Entregues"
"Total Shipping","Total de Envios"
"Refunds Report","Relatório de Reembolsos"
"Refunded Orders","Pedidos Reembolsados"
"Online Refunds","Reembolsos Online"
"Offline Refunds","Reembolsos Offline"
"Coupons Report","Relatório de Cupons"
"Sales Subtotal","Subtotal de Vendas"
"Cart Price Rule","Regra de Preço no Carrinho"
"PayPal Settlement Reports","Relatórios de liquidação do PayPal"
"Merchant Account","Conta do comerciante"
"Merchant Account ID","ID da conta do comerciante"
"Merchant ID","ID do comerciante"
"Report Date","Data do Relatório"
"Transaction ID","ID da transação"
"Invoice ID","Identificação da Fatura"
"PayPal Reference ID","ID de referência do PayPal"
"Gross Amount","Valor Bruto"
"We are connecting to the PayPal SFTP server to retrieve new reports. Are you sure you want to continue?","Estamos nos conectando ao servidor SFTP do PayPal para recuperar novos relatórios. Tem certeza de que deseja continuar?"
"Fetch Updates","Buscar Atualizações"
"Braintree Settlement Report","Relatório de Liquidação Braintree"
"Apply filters in order to get results. Only first 100 records will be displayed in the grid, you will be able to download full version of the report in .csv format.","Aplicar filtros para obter resultados. Apenas os primeiros 100 registros serão exibidos na grade, você poderá baixar a versão completa do relatório no formato .csv."
"Payment Type","Tipo de pagamento"
"Settlement Code","Código de Liquidação"
"Settlement batch Id","Identificação do lote de liquidação"
"Settlement Response Text","Texto de resposta a liquidação"
"Refund Ids","Id. De Reembolso"
"Order Count Report","Relatório de Contagem de Pedidos"
"Order Total Report","Relatório Total de Pedidos"
"We can't find records for this period.","Não podemos encontrar registros para esse período."
"Show By","Mostrar Por"
"Show By:","Mostrar Por:"
"The report displays the top 5 most viewed products for each interval.","O relatório exibe os 5 melhores produtos mais vistos para cada intervalo."
"Bestsellers Report","Relatório dos mais vendidos"
"Order Quantity","Quantidade de Pedido"
"Low Stock Report","Relatório de Estoque Baixo"
"Stock Quantity","Quantidade de Estoque"
"Ordered Quantity","Quantidade Encomendada"
"Ordered Products Report","Ordered Products Report"
"Purchases","Compras"
"purchases","Compras"
"Downloads Report","Downloads Report"
"Total Ordered Report","Relatório de Produtos Encomendados"
"Order Taxes Report Grouped by Tax Rates","Relatório de Impostos de Pedido Agrupados por Taxas de Imposto"
"Total Shipped Report","Relatório Total Enviado"
"Total Invoiced VS Paid Report","Relatório de Total Faturado VS Pago"
"Total Refunded Report","Relatório Total Reembolsado"
"Promotion Coupons Usage Report","Relatório de Uso de Cupons de Promoção"
"Products Bestsellers Report","Relatório dos Produtos Mais Vendidos"
"Most Viewed Products Report","Relatório dos produtos mais vistos"
"Refresh Statistics for the Last Day","Atualizar Estatísticas do Ultimo Dia"
"Refresh Lifetime Statistics","Atualizar Estatísticas do Tempo de Vida"
"We updated lifetime statistic.","Atualizamos a estatística de vida."
"We can\'t refresh lifetime statistics.","Não pudemos atualizar as estatísticas de vida."
"This is used internally. Make sure you don't use spaces or more than 30 symbols.","Usado internamente. Use até 30 caracteres sem espaços ou acentos"
"Depends on design theme.","Depende do tema de design."
"Position of attribute in layered navigation block.","Posição do atributo no bloco de navegação em camadas."
"Can be used only with catalog input type Dropdown, Multiple Select and Price.","Pode ser usado somente com o catálogo com o tipo de entrada Suspenso, Seleção Múltipla e Preço."
"Entity Type","Tipo de Entidade"
"Export File Format","Exportar Formato de Arquivo"
"Fields Enclosure","Armário de campos"
"Export Settings","Configurações de Exportação"
"Customers Main File","Arquivo Principal dos Clientes"
"Customer Addresses","Endereços do Cliente"
"Various XML configurations that were collected across modules and merged","Várias configurações XML que foram coletadas em módulos e mescladas"
"Layout building instructions","Instruções de construção do layout"
"Blocks HTML output","Bloos de saída HTML"
"Page blocks HTML","Blocos de páginas HTML"
"Collections Data","Dados das coleções"
"Collection data files","Arquivos de dados da coleção"
"Reflection Data","Dados de Reflexão"
"API interfaces reflection data","Dados de reflexão das interfaces da API"
"Database DDL operations","Operações DDL de banco de dados"
"Results of DDL queries, such as describing tables or indexes","Resultados de consultas DDL, como descrever tabelas ou índices"
"EAV types and attributes","EAV tipos e atributos"
"Entity types declaration cache","Cache de entidades declaradas"
"Customer Notification","Notificação do Cliente"
"Page Cache","Cache de página"
"Full page caching","Armazenamento em Página Completo"
"Integrations Configuration","Configuração de Integração"
"Integration configuration file.","Arquivo de configuração de integração."
"Integrations API Configuration","Configuração da API de Integração"
"Integrations API configuration file","Arquivo de configuração da Integração da API"
"Web Services Configuration","Configuração dos Serviços da Web"
"REST and SOAP configurations, generated WSDL file","Configurações REST e SOAP, arquivo WSDL gerado"
"Pregenerated product images files","Arquivos de imagens de produtos pré-gerados"
"Themes JavaScript and CSS files combined to one file","Arquivos JavaScript e CSS dos Temas combinados em um arquivo"
"Preprocessed view files and static files","Arquivos de visualização préprocessados e arquivos estáticos"
```

The folder of custom package language extended of a package in vendor, is:

```
app/i18n/MyCompany/magentoptbr
```

contains the files:

```
composer.json
language.xml
module-backend.csv
module-email.csv
pt_BR.csv
registration.php
```

I dont know what to do, please help. thanks in advance